# What type of Mixed Method is this?

Tags: mixed-model, methodology

Really confused about this as have never done a mixed methods study before.

The study in a nutshell – participant does brief test battery, then is interviewed for 15 mins. Some interview questions require Likert scale answers.

Then they undergo an intervention – using a computer application for a week.

Then I re-interview them asking them similar questions from the first interview of which some have Likert responses.

I'm using the interview questions to explore their answers and compare the changes after intervention. Its partly comparing qualitative data before and after, and comparing Likert scale data before and after (non-parametric I think). I'm using the test battery just to ascertain a cognitive profile which is important to understanding their responses at interview, and will hope to compare that quantitative data with the Likert scale data.

From looking at the mixed methods literature I think it could be several designs. Two phase embedded Qualitative(quantitative) design or sequential convergent triangulation or embedded experimental design. Can't figure it out.

Would really appreciate any thoughts on this at all. Feels like I've bitten off more than I can chew!

Answer (score 1):

One problem with mixed methods is that there is a glut of terminology (Tashakkori & Teddlie, 2010). What you describe does not sound sequential, but instead it seems to be a parallel mixed design (Teddlie & Tashakkori, 2009).

Comment: Your answer would be improved by providing a full citation (and a link if available).